# How to override core liferay 7.1 language interface to override its methods

Tags: liferay, liferay-7.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9988.png)I want to override LIferay 7.1 language interface where I will write the code to fetch the properties from our custom table and assign it to key rather than taking liferay translation or from properties file

```
public class CustomLanguageImpl implements Language {
this is my custom class trying to override language interface

public class CustomLanguageImpl implements Language {

    @Override
    public String format(HttpServletRequest request, String pattern, LanguageWrapper argument) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String format(HttpServletRequest request, String pattern, LanguageWrapper argument,
            boolean translateArguments) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String format(HttpServletRequest request, String pattern, LanguageWrapper[] arguments) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String format(HttpServletRequest request, String pattern, LanguageWrapper[] arguments,
            boolean translateArguments) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String format(HttpServletRequest request, String pattern, Object argument) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String format(HttpServletRequest request, String pattern, Object argument, boolean translateArguments) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String format(HttpServletRequest request, String pattern, Object[] arguments) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String format(HttpServletRequest request, String pattern, Object[] arguments, boolean translateArguments) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String format(Locale locale, String pattern, List<Object> arguments) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String format(Locale locale, String pattern, Object argument) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String format(Locale locale, String pattern, Object argument, boolean translateArguments) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String format(Locale locale, String pattern, Object[] arguments) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String format(Locale locale, String pattern, Object[] arguments, boolean translateArguments) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String format(ResourceBundle resourceBundle, String pattern, Object argument) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String format(ResourceBundle resourceBundle, String pattern, Object argument, boolean translateArguments) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String format(ResourceBundle resourceBundle, String pattern, Object[] arguments) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String format(ResourceBundle resourceBundle, String pattern, Object[] arguments,
            boolean translateArguments) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String get(HttpServletRequest request, ResourceBundle resourceBundle, String key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String get(HttpServletRequest request, ResourceBundle resourceBundle, String key, String defaultValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String get(HttpServletRequest request, String key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String get(HttpServletRequest request, String key, String defaultValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String get(Locale locale, String key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String get(Locale locale, String key, String defaultValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String get(ResourceBundle resourceBundle, String key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String get(ResourceBundle resourceBundle, String key, String defaultValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Locale> getAvailableLocales() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Locale> getAvailableLocales(long groupId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBCP47LanguageId(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBCP47LanguageId(Locale locale) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getBCP47LanguageId(PortletRequest portletRequest) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Locale> getCompanyAvailableLocales(long companyId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLanguageId(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLanguageId(Locale locale) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getLanguageId(PortletRequest portletRequest) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Locale getLocale(long groupId, String languageCode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Locale getLocale(String languageCode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceBundleLoader getPortalResourceBundleLoader() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Locale> getSupportedLocales() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTimeDescription(HttpServletRequest request, long milliseconds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTimeDescription(HttpServletRequest request, long milliseconds, boolean approximate) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTimeDescription(HttpServletRequest request, Long milliseconds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTimeDescription(Locale locale, long milliseconds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTimeDescription(Locale locale, long milliseconds, boolean approximate) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTimeDescription(Locale locale, Long milliseconds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAvailableLanguageCode(String languageCode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAvailableLocale(Locale locale) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAvailableLocale(long groupId, Locale locale) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAvailableLocale(long groupId, String languageId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAvailableLocale(String languageId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isBetaLocale(Locale locale) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDuplicateLanguageCode(String languageCode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInheritLocales(long groupId) throws PortalException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSameLanguage(Locale locale1, Locale locale2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String process(ResourceBundle resourceBundle, Locale locale, String content) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void resetAvailableGroupLocales(long groupId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resetAvailableLocales(long companyId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void updateCookie(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Getting Import-Package: com.liferay.portal.kernel.language; version="[7.2.0,7.3.0)"_ [Sanitized]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444) error while deploying the portlet

Comment: It looks like you need to get the correct dependencies for your application. Which version of Liferay are you using CE or EE?

Comment: Liferay 7.1 version EE

Comment: The generated Java file that you post is quite useless to get to the bottom of this problem. Please edit your question to have the full setup of your project, e.g. build instructions, declared dependencies, so that it's obvious what you're doing and can be reproduced. Without that, it's hard to assume what you're doing.

Comment: Hi @OlafKock there is an ext has been created in 6.2 liferay for language trasnlation which uses values from customtable name tpllanguagetranslation instead of using liferay translation values so there they overridden the liferay's language interface and i need to implement same in liferay 7.1,i have pasted the screen shot of liferay 6.2